# Kubernetes pod not creating - Azure AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

my pod was stuck on ContainerCreating state. The describe of pod says:

```
  Type     Reason                  Age    From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               2m28s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned namespacex/web.app-b7b8b6649-x2gg9 to akswin000002
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  24s    kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "web.app-b7b8b6649-x2gg9": operation timeout: context deadline exceeded
```

after some research I could find the command

```
kubectl get ds -n kube-system
```

that returned:

```
NAME                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   
AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/azure-ip-masq-agent      3         3         3       3            3           <none>          146d
daemonset.apps/csi-azuredisk-node       3         3         3       3            3           <none>          146d
daemonset.apps/csi-azuredisk-node-win   3         3         1       3            1           <none>          146d
daemonset.apps/csi-azurefile-node       3         3         3       3            3           <none>          146d
daemonset.apps/csi-azurefile-node-win   3         3         1       3            1           <none>          146d
daemonset.apps/kube-proxy               3         3         3       3            3           <none>          146d
```

here we can see that 2 deployments have 1 ready but 3 desired. Whats going on and how to solve it? Its deployed in a Windows Cluster on AKS service.

Comment: can you provide the .yaml file ?

Answer (score 0):

So, this daemonset is part of the AKS config so Windows nodes can access storage on Azure Storage. Does your app requests persistent storage? Also, by the name of the node on which the pod was schedulded (akswin000002) you have three nodes (and that matches the output you provided). It seems two Windows nodes have issues bringing these daemonsets up, but these should be resolved after a while.

Can you run kubectl get ds and then describe the ds with the fail state?